# Scroll Listview to bottom after items loaded in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to scroll the Listview to bottom after the Widget is rendered. 
Tried the below code, but its being called before the Listview is rendered.

```
  ScrollController _lvScrollCtrl = new ScrollController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
    loadListviewData();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _lvScrollCtrl.animateTo(_lvScrollCtrl.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeOut);
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

I have also tried setting the reverse property of Listview to true. But this brings all items to the bottom of Expanded widget. 
I just wanted a normal Listview scrolled down to the end to show recent updates on Load. :/

Answer (score 1):

I moved the below code to the build function before return statement, and it's working perfect. Just realized addPostFrameCallback callback will be called only once after the current frame is finished. So I needed to set it again and again to keep it calling.

```
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _lvScrollCtrl.animateTo(_lvScrollCtrl.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeOut);
    });
```